# Show differentiation a linear operator in three dimensional space.

Tags: linear-algebra

> To find:
>   Show $D=\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}$ is a linear operator on the 3-dimensional space of "quasi-polynomials"
>   $$e^t(a_2t^2 + a_1t + a_0)$$
>
> a) Using $(e^t,te^t,t^2e^t)$ as a basis, write out the corresponding 
>   matrix.
>   b) Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of D. Is D diagonisable?
>   c) Find the inverse mapping, hence solve the differential equation
>    $$\frac{\mathrm{d}f(t) }{\mathrm{d} t}=e^t(b_2t^2 + b_1t + b_0)$$

Comment: The word "quasi-polynomial" is inadequate : you will find it nowhere for the product of a polynomial with an exponential, just because the exponential dominates the polynomial...

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far so that we can provide you with better advice

Comment: $$D(e^t)=e^t$$ $$D(te^t)=e^t (t+1)$$$$D(t^2e^t)=e^t (t)(t+2)$$

Comment: >further $$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  1& 0\\ 
 0&1  &2 \\ 
 0&  0&1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Do you know anything in particular about the eigenvalues of upper-triangular matrices?

Comment: the eigenvalues of T consist precisely of the entries on the diagonal of that upper-triangular matrix.